# Saving user feedback in a text file

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

i am trying to make some kind of contact form for my website and i am looking for a php code to save what user entered in contact form in a txt file on my host server.

i have made some researches about contact forms and it seems the usual way is to send emails but every code i tried didn't worked and it alway throws SMTP Connect() failed exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';

if ($email && $message) {
    $str = $email . '-' . $message . "<br/>";
    $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
    echo fwrite($file, $str);
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```